# jQuery bind a click event within two iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe, bind

I have a page where I have included a chat program(third party), it includes a chat window within an iframe. So now I want to bind the button click event in the parent document.

Below is the hierarchy:-

> Main Document > iframe > iframe >Chat Window button(bind this button to Grand parent
>   document)

I tried this code

```
<script>
$(window).ready(function($){

    var frameWindow = $('#livservMiddleFrame').get(0).contentWindow;
    console.log(frameWindow.document.body.innerHTML);

});
</script>
```

This gives me the output of the first iframes HTML, this was just a try. I dont know whether it is possible or can we get it through some hijack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my personal experience with iframes, I've found it to be more reliable to use plain JS to "fetch" iframe objects. Say you have DOM > iframe1 > iframe2 > chat-button, this is how you can fetch the windoe objects:

```
var frame1Win = window.frames["iframe1"].window; // "iframe1" is iframe name, not id
var frame2Win = frame1Win.frames["iframe2"].window;
```

PS: You might have to use contentWindow depending on your browser.

And you can use the following way to attach click event using JQuery

```
$(frame2Win).find("#chat-button").on("click",function() {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: the problem is that the second or the last iframe doesn't has a name attribute is their any alternate of it

Comment: In that case, you can use frames as an array like: `frame[0]`. I hope number of iframes2 inside iframe1 are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make changes in an iframe using javascript or jquery. but again you can check the following code. It may help you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('button').click(function() {

});
});
```

Comment: this works for the first iframes button, not for the iframe within iframe

Comment: you could try $('iframe iframe') instead